# Can you *abolish* a human capacity?

Tags: single-word-requests

Which verb can make a human capacity cease to exist (e.g. by social or technological change)? Can you e.g. "abolish this human capacity"?

[late edit:] I am looking for a word with pessimistic undertones. Think for example of developments that would render it impossible to hide some sensitive information and keep it secret, or that would render it impossible to make certain choices and calculations by yourself, stories about the demise or extermination of human faculties, freedoms and capacities...

Comment: Can you include an example sentence where this word would be used? The following is the rule of this community. **Questions on choosing 

an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be 

used in order to be answered**. For help writing a good word or 

phrase request, see: [About single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). 

Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Which human capacity you are referring to? Sentience?

Comment: The complement of **abolish** is usually an institutionalized practice or the system enabling it, not a *capability*.  If you wish to cast this human capacity in that light it's your choice, but **abolish** doesn't strike me as the *mot juste*. Whatever word you choose, it will have a metaphorical element: rout out, eradicate, render obsolete, erase, kill, remove.

Comment: Your late edit suggests that "human capacity" wasn't the best phrase. *Human* suggests something *innate*.  You're talking about political freedoms ("choices and calculations"). They *can* be abolished.

Comment: You can certainly use "abolish" is a metaphoric/hyperbolic sense, even if it isn't literally appropriate.  It's up to you, of course, to judge whether such use conveys the intended meaning.

Answer (score 1):

As per the context you have provided in one of your comments below, you may consider ***[obliterate](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/obliterate)***, that has negative connotations.

> (verb): to remove or destroy all traces of; do away with; destroy completely.

[Dictionary.com]

**Usage:**

> The technological evolution has **obliterated** human creativity/capacity.

Comment: Except that I wouldn't use it as a verb - sounds hideous.

Comment: thanks, BiscuitBoy. Maybe I weren't clear about it-- I am looking for a word with more pessimistic undertones. Think for example of developments that would render it impossible to hide some sensitive information and keep it secret, or that would render it impossible to make certain choices and calculation yourself (I could offer here more examples, but I guess it's clear now), i.e., stories about the demise or extermination of human faculties, freedoms and capacities... Would "abolish" work here?

Comment: @WS2 - One word - *['Murica](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/obsolete#Verb)* ! ;)

Comment: @stultissimus - In that case, I'd prefer [obliterate](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/obliterate). *Abolish* would be associated with things like "abolishing tax laws" or "abolishing discrimination". P.S: You should update this context in your question

Comment: Why not delete the "obsolete" part? It became irrelevant after the OP's edit I am afraid.

Comment: Since some users had commented on it, I just added an updated, without deleting what I had written previously. But someone had downvoted :( . Your suggestion makes sense and I was pondering about it too.But I wasn't sure if I could delete part of my answer after receiving a  few comments about it. I have now removed the irrelevant part and re-posted my answer.